# What look and feel does ubuntu use?

Tags: java, linux, swing, look-and-feel

What look and feel does ubuntu use, (11 or higher)? I want to use the same in a swing application that will run on windows. Where can I find the jar for that lnf?

Comment: assuming your main question is how to run the gtk (aka system *nix LAF) on another OS: not possible, even is you grab its sources (which are not included in jdks of other OS) from openjdk. It heavily relies on OS method calls which won't compile, out-commenting leaves you with ... nothing painted :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java supports a `SystemLookAndFeel` that attempts to match the look of the native applications in each operating system, which is what I assume you want to do. I don't know how well it succeeds in that task, though.

There is an official tutorial on the look and feel settings [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

**EDIT:**

This snippet (plus any exception handling) seems to work pretty well on my Linux system

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I did not test it extensively but it certainly looks more at home than the default look.

If you want to reproduce the GTK theme on an different computer you can try this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
```

`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel` is what `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` returns on Linux systems for recent Sun JREs. You may encounter problems if you use a JRE from a different vendor.

That said, I am not sure how closely this would match the real thing when used on a non-Linux OS. If I were you, I would install a Linux distribution on a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) virtual machine and try my application in a proper testing environment.

Comment: yeah but i want to replicate that lnf on diff system. so i cant use the System look n feel for that purpose.